# Bluetooth HFP Inquiry

Tags: hfp

My terminal device will connect with client device via Bluetooth connection, but some client devices support HFP and A2DP, client device's A2DP can only be enabled after HFP connection is successful. 
The HFP profile in my terminal device is used for HFP connection purpose, not use for pick up call and talk.
Can my terminal device enable HFP profile without microphone and without phone pick-up button?

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can. however you need either configure that your terminal does not support SCO or just reject the SCO request from phone when in case of phone want to establish the SCO link.